# Mapping Scala Futures

Tags: scala

Let's say I have a `Future[Seq[Int]]` which I want to convert to `Future[Seq[String]]`.  Currently I'm doing it like this:

```
 val futureSeqString = futureSeqInt.map( x => x.map(_.toString()))
```

This works but the nested map seems a bit awkward.  The equivalent conversion for `Future[Option[Int]]` is slightly better but it still doesn't feel like I'm doing it the best way:

```
val futureOptionString = futureOptionInt.map {       
  case Some(x) => x.toString(); 
  case _ => None;
}
```

Is there a better way of dealing with this?

Comment: Option has a map method, so you could (I think should) do the conversion in the same way you've done it for Seq.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The double nesting requires a double mapping, so yes, in vanilla scala, what you're doing is correct.

However, if we consider the theory for a second, both `List` and `Future` have a `map` operation and this makes them `Functors` (this is an oversimplification, but bear with me)

Two `Functors` can be generically composed, so you can compose the `Functor` of `Future` and the `Functor` of `List` to implement a "joint" `map` operation.

Here's an example using [`cats`](https://github.com/typelevel/cats):

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import cats._
import cats.std.future._
import cats.std.list._

// create a `Functor[Future[List]`
val futureListF = Functor[Future].compose(Functor[List])

val data = Future.successful(List(1, 2, 3))

// only one map!    
futureListF.map(data)(_.toString) // Future(List("1", "2", "3"))
```

And of course you can do the same with `Option`.

```
val futureOptionF = Functor[Future].compose(Functor[Option])
val data = Future.successful(Option(42))
futureOptionF.map(data)(_.toString) // Future(Some("42"))
```

Bonus, you can use the same technique regardless of the depth of nesting:

```
type ListOption[+A] = List[Option[A]]
implicit val listOptionF = Functor[List].compose(Functor[Option])
val futureListOptionF = Functor[Future].compose(Functor[ListOption])

// the above three lines could just be
// val futureListOptionF = Functor[Future].compose(Functor[List].compose(Functor[Option]))
// if only SI-2712 were fixed

val data = Future.successful(List(Some(42), None, Some(2)))

// triple nesting? Still a single map!
futureListOptionF.map(data)(_.toString) // Future(List(Some("42"), None, Some("2")))
```

Comment: one minor thing: the OP has a Future[Seq[Int]] not Future[List[Int]] so he is forced to do a double mapping anyway to convert Seq to List

Comment: `Seq` is an abstract trait, whose default implementation is `List`, so the OP's `Seq` is likely to be a `List` already. Otherwise, more details on the specific use case are needed

Comment: but I think it looks at the type not the concrete value so also if you have val data: Future[Seq[Int]] = Future.successful(List(1, 2, 3)) you need to manually convert it to List to make it work

Comment: @lambdista absolutely, I just meant that the type is probably more generic than it could be. If the OP is ok with using `List` instead of `Seq` directly, then it's much easier :)

Comment: ah ok. Subtype polymorphism must die! :)

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I don't see anything wrong with nested maps. You just have to format and indent it better:

```
  future.map { seq =>
    seq.map(_.toString)
  }
```

Some people also find `for` comprehension useful in this case (and more so, when you need to process several futures together).

```
 for {
   seq <- future
 } yield seq.map(_.toString)
```